# R text mining - remove special characters and quotes

Tags: r, regex, text, gsub, mining

I'm doing a text mining task in R.

## Tasks:

1) count sentences

2) identify and save quotes in a vector

## Problems :

False full stops like "..." and periods in titles like "Mr." have to be dealt with.

There's definitely quotes in the text body data, and there'll be "..." in them. I was thinking to extract those quotes from the main body and save them in a vector. (there's some manipulation to be done with them too.)

IMPORTANT TO NOTE : My text data is in a Word document. I use readtext("path to .docx file") to load in R. When I view the text, quotes are just " but not \" contrarily to the reproducible text.

```
path <- "C:/Users/.../"
a <- readtext(paste(path, "Text.docx", sep = ""))
title <- a$doc_id
text <- a$text
```

## reproducible text

```
text <- "Mr. and Mrs. Keyboard have two children. Keyboard Jr. and Miss. Keyboard. ... 
However, Miss. Keyboard likes being called Miss. K [Miss. Keyboard is a bit of a princess ...]
 \"Mom how are you o.k. with being called Mrs. Keyboard? I'll never get it...\". "


#  splitting by "." 
unlist(strsplit(text, "\\."))
```

The problem is it's splitting by false full-stops
Solution I tried:

```
# getting rid of . in titles 
vec <- c("Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ms.", "Miss.", "Dr.", "Jr.")
vec.rep <- c("Mr", "Mrs", "Ms", "Miss", "Dr", "Jr")

library(gsubfn)
# replacing . in titles
gsubfn("\\S+", setNames(as.list(vec.rep), vec), text)
```

The problem with this is that it's not replacing [Miss. by [Miss

To identify quotes :

```
stri_extract_all_regex(text, '"\\S+"')
```

but that's not working too. (It's working with \" with the code below)

```
stri_extract_all_regex("some text \"quote\" some other text", '"\\S+"')
```

The exact expected vector is :

```
sentences <- c("Mr and Mrs Keyboard have two children. ", "Keyboard Jr and Miss Keyboard.", "However, Miss Keyboard likes being called Miss K [Miss Keyboard is a bit of a princess ...]", ""Mom how are you ok with being called Mrs Keyboard? I'll never get it...""
```

I wanted the sentences separated (so I can count how many sentences in each paragraph). 
And quotes also separated.

```
quotes <- ""Mom how are you ok with being called Mrs Keyboard? I'll never get it...""
```

Comment: It is weird you have a full stop after `Miss` as it is not an abbreviation. Even if you remove a dot with `text <- gsub("Miss.", "Miss", text, fixed=TRUE)`, I cannot leverage the `tm` / `OpenNLP` package as it parses out a `[4] "However, Miss Keyboard likes being called Miss K [Miss Keyboard is a bit of a princess ...]\n \"Mom how are you o.k. with being called Mrs. Keyboard?"` sentence. What are your sentence separation rules? Should any text in double quotation mark be extracted as is, even if there are multiple sentences inside?

Comment: What is the expected result for the above text?

Comment: However, Miss Keyboard likes being called Miss K [Miss Keyboard is a bit of a princess ...] is a sentence and "Mom how are you o.k. with being called Mrs. Keyboard?" is another since they are separated by a \n

Comment: yes whole quotations need to be extracted

Comment: expected result is extracting sentences despite the false periods. And extracting whole quotes

Comment: Please update the question itself. Add the exact expected character vector.

Comment: Ok, you may match all your current `vec` values using `gsubfn("\\w+\\.", setNames(as.list(vec.rep), vec), text)`. Note this won't handle `o.k.`. You might use another approach for that. But splitting into sentences does not seem clear.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew The above code worked great with dealing with false periods thank you! Would you have a solution for the second part of the question : extracting whole quotes from a text and saving them in a vector?

Comment: If you just want to extract quotes, try `regmatches(text, gregexpr('"[^"]*"', text))`

Comment: Perfect Wiktor thank you! If you want to post an answer and I'll accept it. Otherwise I can summarize and post your answers, upto you. Cheers.

Comment: I have tried something like `regmatches(text, gregexpr('\\s*"[^"]*"|[^"?!.]+(?:\\s|[?!.])+[^"[:alnum:]]*', trimws(text)))`. Is it any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match all your current `vec` values using

```
gsubfn("\\w+\\.", setNames(as.list(vec.rep), vec), text)
```

That is, `\w+` matches 1 or more word chars and `\.` matches a dot.

Next, if you just want to extract quotes, use

```
regmatches(text, gregexpr('"[^"]*"', text))
```

The `"` matches a `"` and `[^"]*` matches 0 or more chars other than `"`.

If you plan to match your sentences together with quotes, you might consider

```
regmatches(text, gregexpr('\\s*"[^"]*"|[^"?!.]+[[:space:]?!.]+[^"[:alnum:]]*', trimws(text)))
```

**Details**

- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `"[^"]*"` - a `"`, 0+ chars other than `"` and a `"`
- `|` - or
- `[^"?!.]+` - 0+ chars other than `?`, `"`, `!` and `.`
- `[[:space:]?!.]+` - 1 or more whitespace, `?`, `!` or `.` chars
- `[^"[:alnum:]]*` - 0+ non-alphanumeric and `"` chars

R sample code:

```
> vec <- c("Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ms.", "Miss.", "Dr.", "Jr.")
> vec.rep <- c("Mr", "Mrs", "Ms", "Miss", "Dr", "Jr")
> library(gsubfn)
> text <- gsubfn("\\w+\\.", setNames(as.list(vec.rep), vec), text)
> regmatches(text, gregexpr('\\s*"[^"]*"|[^"?!.]+[[:space:]?!.]+[^"[:alnum:]]*', trimws(text)))
[[1]]
[1] "Mr and Mrs Keyboard have two children. "                                                       
[2] "Keyboard Jr and Miss Keyboard. ... \n"                                                         
[3] "However, Miss Keyboard likes being called Miss K [Miss Keyboard is a bit of a princess ...]\n "
[4] "\"Mom how are you o.k. with being called Mrs Keyboard? I'll never get it...\""
```